# Convert Proc created on the fly to source code or Sexp

Tags: ruby

I need to **convert** `Proc` object to **source code** or **s-expression** in Ruby 1.9. The tricky part is that `Proc` object is **created on the fly** and doesn't exist in any file, so I cannot use [Sourcify](https://github.com/ngty/sourcify/). How can I handle this?

Feel free to ask any questions if you need clarification.

Comment: @sawa: actually, it may be created by different means, but I use creation from REPL as test case for the moment. E.g. `> p = Proc.new{x = 1}`.